# ES6, access props set by the child from the parent's constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, ecmascript-6

I am trying to set up a class hierarchy with ES6 classes.

All entities will inherit from single `Base` class. It will need to access properties exposed by the `Child` class in a generic manner. Like this:

```
class Base {
    constructor() {
        this.doSomethingWithProps();
    }

    doSomethingWithProps() {
        console.log(Object.keys(this));
    }
}

class Entity extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.key = "value";
    }
}
```

Obviously, in the example above, `Base` class will not see the `key` prop set up by `Entity`. Ideally I would move the `this` assignment before `super()`, but that's not allowed. It would also be nice to be able to set properties before constructor, but AFAIK, that's not possible either.

The only solution I am left with is doing something like the following in each `Entity`:

```
class Base {
    doSomethingWithProps() {
        console.log(Object.keys(this));
    }
}

class Entity extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.key = "value";

        this.doSomethingWithProps();
    }
}
```

However, besides being less than ideal, it will also create problems if I then want to inherit from `Entity`. `doSomethingWithProps` would then need to be able to detect if it's the "top-most" method in call hierarchy and only do its thing then. The only way to achieve *that* (that I can think of) would involve *even more* boilerplate.

Is there some solution I'm missing here? I'd be open to using a different OOP pattern if needed, although I'd like to stay as close as possible to native ES6 classes.

Comment: Generally it is better to rely on composition rather than inheritance as it could lead to a fragile base class. You can still use classes but inject another class in that contains the methods you need. This may also help if you do go down the class route: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/how-to-use-classes-and-sleep-at-night-9af8de78ccb4#.mdwl0ilzj

Comment: If a base class has knowledge about derived classes, then something's utterly wrong.

Comment: @zeroflagL it doesn't exactly, just does generic initialize logic.  Eg. coerce all properties, validate that nothing illegal is assigned etc. Sanity checks that are necessary due to dynamic nature of js.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is quite impossible. The parent initialisation always runs before the child initialisation, so it is imperative that the parent constructor does not rely on properties that might be overwritten by the child. This is a language-agnostic problem, btw.

The solution is to use parameters for the constructor, which can be modified in the child before they reach the parent code:

```
class Base {
    constructor(key) {
        this.key = key;
        // do something with key
    }
}

class Entity extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super("value");
    }
}

console.log(new Entity);
```

or more generic

```
class Base {
    constructor(props) {
        this.doSomething(props);
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }

    doSomething(props) {
        return Object.keys(props);
    }
}

class Entity extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super({key: "value"});
    }
}

console.log(new Entity);
```

Also notice that constructors should always be pure. Their only purpose is to initialise the new instance from the arguments, and do nothing else like execute some side effects. A constructor should usually not need to call any (overwritable) instance methods (static methods are ok though).
So if you need to do something like that nonetheless when creating your instances, just don't do it in the constructor. Instead, call a method after using the constructor:

```
class Base {
    log() {
        console.log(Object.keys(this));
        return this;
    }
}

class Entity extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.key = "value";
    }
}

var e = new Entity().log();
```

You can also abstract that out:

```
class Base {
    static createAndLog(...args) {
        var x = new this(...args);
        x.log();
        return x;
    }
    …
}
…

var e = Entity.createAndLog();
```

Comment: In the first pattern, `Entity` class is left without a clear public interface for IDE-s, eyes and linters to pick out. The second idea, with the factory, is fine. The downside is that you are then reliant on the specific special interface built around classes, which is less universal than `new`.

Comment: @panta82 If you mean the second snippet with `Object.assign`, yes that could be a problem. Maybe don't use `Object.assign` but pass the object *and* also assign to `this.key`. It all depends on what specifically you need to do with the value. In general, a class should not need to know anything about the additional properties of its children classes.

Comment: @panta82 Regarding the second pattern, you can still use `new`, but if you want to use your special feature you also have to call `.log()` at some time (which doesn't necessarily need to be immediately after the instantiation). Again, it depends on what that method would do; the `createAndLog` factory only can help to avoid some code duplication but is not always useful.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complex you want to go, there's probably two routes you could go down.

#### 1. Keep state in `Base`

If possible, pass the props you need from Entity into Base and maintain state there.

```js
class Base {
    constructor(props) {
        for (var k in props) {
          this[k] = props[k]
        }
        this.doSomethingWithProps();
    }

    doSomethingWithProps() {
      console.log(Object.keys(this));
    }
}

class Entity extends Base {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
}

let entity = new Entity({key: 'value'})
// ["key"]
```

#### 2. Pass reference  to `Entity` into `Base`

*Note, I was incorrectly assuming separate instances of Entity.. this is overly redundant.*

Not as simple, and will technically contain a self referencing key as `Entity` will inherit the `child` key from `Base`. This would definitely be considered a "wrong" approach, but I'm including it for the heck of it.

```js
class Base {
    constructor() {
      this.child
    }
    
    registerChild(child) {
      this.child = child
      this.doSomethingWithProps()
    }
    
    doSomethingWithProps() {
      console.log(Object.keys(this.child));
    }
}

class Entity extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.key = 'value'
        this.registerChild(this)
    }
}

let entity = new Entity()
// ["key", "child"]
```

Comment: Your second snippet (the one with `registerChild`) has exactly the same problem as calling `this.doSomethingWithProps()` from the `Entity` constructor (see the question)

Comment: @Bergi Good point.. I think I was going more from two separate instances needed access to the `Entity`, not inheritance.

Comment: The problem with 1 is that `Entity` will then be seen as empty class by the IDE. No intellisense :(  The problem with 2 was pointed out by @Bergi

Answer (score 0):

I think the observation here should be: avoid calling a method that relies on the object's state in the constructor, since constructors are meant to build that state.

Comment: The problem is when you have derived state. Nice theory, but falls apart in reality.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you suppose to ask is about js syntax, however, the root of the issue is the idea of **oop**

Consider what `extends` mean when you write:

```
Entity extends Base
```

It means `Entity` make use of something from `Base`, the keyword is `extends` rather than something like `communicate`, which means `Base` **should NOT**  care about `Entity` at the first place. `extends` can also mean `Entity` has something which is not expected by `Base`, thus `extends`.

However, from my own point of view(correct me if I am wrong), there are some valid use cases in which parent class has some awareness of child class.
For example: put some common logic in Parent class to manipulate the property of Child, in such case, from the point of view of logic(not syntax), the child property should be `static`, i.e. belong to the whole class rather than a instance

Comment: So how would you achieve that parent `communicates` with child?